# C# Change Object Value Through Another Class

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to change an object value from other class. Ideally, I want to pass the object as parameter into constructor/method. What I've read so far, object behaves as reference when passed as parameter, and parameter value are copied locally for use in the method's body. So here are few configuration that I tested:

Case #1. Failed

```
class Processor 
{
   DataTable table;

   public Processor(DataTable table)
   {
       this.table = table;
   }

   public void InitializeTable()
   {
       if (table != null)
       {
           // Fill data into DataTable.
       }
   }
}

static void Main(string[] args) 
{
   DataTable mainTable = new DataTable();

   Processor processor = new Processor(mainTable);
   processor.InitializeTable();
   // mainTable still empty       
}
```

I thought `Processor` table holds the same reference to `mainTable`, but by the end of `Main` execution `mainTable` was still EMPTY while `Processor` table was filled.

Case #2. Failed

```
public Processor(ref DataTable table)
{
   this.table = table;
}
```

I've tried using `ref` signature, but result still the same (`mainTable` was EMPTY).

Case #3. Failed

```
public void InitializeTable(DataTable table)
{
   // Fill data into table
}
```

I've removed the constructor and feed `mainTable` into `InitializeTable()` method, and result still the same (`mainTable` was EMPTY).

Case #4. Works!

```
public void InitializeTable(ref DataTable table)
{
   // Fill data into table
}
```

Finally this works! Feeding `ref mainTable` into `InitializeTable` now fills `mainTable` successfully. What are the explanation behind this? Why constructor didn't have the same reference to `mainTable`? Why `ref` keyword still needed when passing object as parameter already means passing its reference?

Comment: What does `InitializeTable()` actually do?  In the first entire example I would certainly expect `mainTable` to reflect any changes made, since only one actual `DataTable` is ever instantiated in memory.

Comment: Simple query to get data from database, and assign it to table. Yeah i do have the same assumption too, but only case #4 filled mainTable.

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "assign it to table"?  If the code isn't doing what you expect, don't just vaguely describe the code and assume it must be working, actually examine it.

Comment: @David   
`if (table != null)  
{  
   DB.IP = "localhost";  
   DB.ConnectCore();  
   table = DB.SelectArray("SELECT TOP 3 TransCode, TransDate FROM 
      CBN..SalesOrder", null);  
   DB.Disconnect();  
}`

Comment: Then that explains the behavior.  You're re-assigning the local `table` variable to a new `DataTable` instance (returned by `.SelectArray()`).  So it no longer refers to the same instance as the `mainTable` variable and no longer modifies that instance.

Comment: @David Thanks David, that's a sound argument. The DB.SelectArray(string, object[]) does return DataTable type, so i guess you're right.  
But what made Case #4 still possible? InitializeTable() body doesn't change for the 4 cases

Comment: Because in the fourth case you're passing a `ref` parameter, which allows the assignment to that variable to carry back to the variable that was passed to it.  There's information about what the `ref` keyword means here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref

Comment: @David I sincerely thanked you David. You've just demystified my long doubt about object reference. Have a nice day, God bless you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit goes to David:

> Then that explains the behavior. You're re-assigning the local table
>   variable to a new DataTable instance (returned by .SelectArray()). So
>   it no longer refers to the same instance as the mainTable variable and
>   no longer modifies that instance.